# Why does association mix sites?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, association

I just disassociated all my accounts. Then on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/357313?tab=accounts) I pressed `Associate with Meta Stack Overflow`. After that, both Stack Overflow and Meta showed:

> **You've associated your Stack Overflow and Area 51 accounts: +100 reputation**

I do have a Area 51 account, but that one was not involved. Is there a bug somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can no longer permanently dissociate your accounts, i.e. when you log in anew on a site, it will automatically be associated with *all* your accounts, including the SE-2.0 betas (which apparently count as "Area 51 accounts")

Comment: Ah, I guess I noticed that.